# ASP.net dataview in outproc session state

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net Application, we were using `InProc` session state, now we have changed it to `OutProc` (StateServer or SQLServer).

In the pages where we have used dataview in session, it is throwing error "***Unable to serialize the session state***.

In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.", I don't want to change all the files.

How to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

Check all you objects which you put in the session if they are serializable objects or not MarshalByRef objects. You have at least one of those in you session. If you remove that item from your session you will be able to save the session OutProc.

Comment: we are storing dataview in session which is not serializable but we are using it in many files, so Is there any alternative for either making dataview serializable or doing it without doing so many changes.

Comment: You can serialize the DataTable of the dataview. The DataView itself holds no data.